# "this method is not applicable for the arguments" error

Tags: java, syntax-error, processing

Anyone know why I get this error? Essentially this program displays an image, displays the histogram or the image. It then adjust each pixels brightness and once more displays the image and histogram with the adjusted values.

The error is:

> `The method drawHistogram(int[], int, int) is not applicable for arguments (PImage, int[]);`

```
PImage rocks;
PImage rocksBrightened;
PImage rocks2;
int rockBytes[][];
int rockBrights[][];

void setup() {  

  rocks = loadImage("rocks.png");
  size(rocks.width+256, rocks.height*2);
  rocks2 = createGraphics(rocks.width, rocks.height, P2D);
  rocks2.loadPixels();

  int h = rocks.height;
  size(rocks.width*2, rocks.height*2);
  image(rocks, 0, 0);
  rockBytes = new int[rocks.width][rocks.height];
  rockBrights = new int[rocks.width][rocks.height];
  for (int i = 0;i < rocks.width; i++) {  
    for (int j = 0; j < rocks.height; j++) {
    rockBytes[i][j] = rocks.get(i, j);
    } 
  }  
  for (int i = 0; i < rocks.width; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < rocks.height; j++) { 
      rockBrights[i][j] = rocksBrightened.get(i, j); 
      }  
    } 
  drawHistogram(rocks, computeHistogram(rocks)); //THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR
  brighten(rockBrights);
  // makeImage(rocksBrightened, rockBrights);
  image(rocksBrightened, 0, h);
  }

void loadPixelArray(PImage anImage) { 
  anImage.loadPixels(); //load pixels into pixels[] array
  }

int[] computeHistogram (PImage anImage) {
  int histogram[] = new int[256];
  for (int i = anImage.pixels.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
    int v = (int) brightness(anImage.pixels[i]);
    histogram[v]++;
  }
  int maxV = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    maxV = max(maxV,histogram[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    histogram[i] = (int) (histogram[i]*100.0/maxV);
  }
  return histogram; 
}


void brighten(int anyArray[][]) { 

   for (int i = rocks.pixels.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
      int v = rocks.pixels[i];
      float br = brightness(v);
      float r = constrain(br*-.004436+2.1308*red(v),0,255);
      float g = constrain(br*-.004436+2.1308*green(v),0,255);
      float b = constrain(br*-.004436+2.1308*blue(v),0,255);
      rocks2.pixels[i] = color(r,g,b);
      } 
  }

  void drawHistogram(int histogram[], int x, int y) {
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  stroke(255);
  rect(x, y, 256, 256);
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    line(x + i, y+256, x + i, y+256 - histogram[i]);
  }
 }


 void makeImage(PImage anImage, int imgArray[][]) { 

   anImage.loadPixels();
   for (int i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {   
     for (int j = 0; j < imgArray[0].length; j++) {   
     int loc = i + j*imgArray.length;   
     set(i, j+100, color(imgArray[i][j])); 
     } 
   }
   anImage.updatePixels();
}
```

Comment: You might want to show the actual and complete error message as well as indicate which line is causing it.

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Which error? At which line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the error message says it all:

> The method drawHistogram(int[], int, int) is not applicable for arguments (PImage, int[]);

This means that you're trying to call the method `drawHistogram()`, which is declared as `drawHistogram(int[], int, int)` (which means it takes an int array and two ints as arguments), but that you pass a `PImage` and an int array instead of the required arguments. That doesn't make sense.

It's a bit like trying to stick a dollar bill into a machine accepting coins only: it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As JB Nizet said.  To correct this especific error just use the method computeHistogram(), call:

```
drawHistogram(computeHistogram(rocks), x, y);
```

Where x and y are base position to draw histogram. But after that the code will not compile yet. 
There are some others errors that you can go after :)

Comment: would you know why i keep getting NullPointerException ?

Comment: Well null pointer means that you are trying to access some object or variable not yet initialized. Usually with the word "new". If I remember, the first will be the "rockBrights" that will be initialized only after you try to use it. Only reordering should fix that. The next will be "rocksBrightened" that is already declared but not initialized when you try to use it.